# knative helloworld does not run microk8s due to x509 certificate issue

Tags: microk8s, knative, knative-serving

I have installed knative on microk8s using ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). I am trying basic knative example , but it's not working. 
1. First I've tried with kn. (kn was not able to read configuration, so I've exported the configuration using `microk8s.config > ~/kubeconfig`

```yaml
kn --kubeconfig ~/kubeconfig service create hello --image gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go --env TARGET=Knative
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.serving.knative.dev": Post "https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/defaulting?timeout=30s": x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match webhook.knative-serving.svc
```

2. I've tried to load using `kubectl create`, but getting the same error.
   Any idea.

Comment: I have enable unverified connections using `kubectl config set-cluster microk8s-cluster --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --server="$CLUSTER_SERVER"` . But still no change in the behavior

Answer (score 0):

What version of Knative are you using?

It looks like your Knative webhook may be generating a certificate with an empty subject. Have you tried connecting to the webhook directly on the cluster via `curl -kvv https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/defaulting`? That should print out the certificate and ignore the validation so that you can test that the service is working.